# Expand brackets around cursor

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a vimscript function that will expand do this:

```
if (condition) { /*Press enter here*/ }
// Turns into this
if (condition)
{
    //Cursor gets placed here
}
```

The comments are not included, they just say what happens.

I started by mapping the enter key in insert mode.

```
inoremap <expr> <cr> OpenBrackets()
```

Next, I started writing the function.  However I'm not great at vimscript, so I don't know how to.  Here is the pseudocode:

```
function! OpenBrackets()
  if "check if cursor is surrounded by brackets.  Ideally check if cursor is inside of a regex pattern.
    normal "expand brackets
  else
    normal <cr>
  endif
endfunction
```

How would I do this with real code?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinvent the wheel, you probably want to take a look at some of the snippet plugins. Some popular ones that would seem to accomplish what you’re after are [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets), [vim-snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate), and [Ultisnips](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-ultisnips/) (feels a little heavy).

Comment: Actually `vim-snippets` is just a collection of snippets.  It's pretty good, but it doesn't do anything by itself, you also need a snippet engine to use it.  `Ultisnips`, `vim-snipmate`, and [neosnippet](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) are such snippet engines that can use `vim-snippets`.  Of these, if your Vim has support for Python, you probably want `Ultisnips`.  It's far more powerful and faster than the others.